# Linux samples BPF is not compiling

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

Just synced up to latest Linux bpf-next repo (5.3.0) and trying to compile samples/bpf directory. The Linux kernel compiles fine. This is on a Linux host and the default config was taken from /boot/config-* and changed to define XDP param. I do have root access to the build machine.

This is what I get and no .o's are seen in the dir.

sudo make samples/bpf/
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  DESCEND  objtool

I have a checkout of the repo (5.2.0-rc*) in a ubuntu VM and the build succeeds fine there.

What am I missing? Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Known issue, please check [this email thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/xdp-newbies/msg01391.html).